# How to add a Hyperlink to a dynamic gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue hope someone can help.

I have a dynamic `Gridview`. I need to have a `hyperlink` on gridview column. These hyperlink should open a popup to display certain data on clicking.

I tried this by having a dynamic template field . But even on binding the data , I'm unable to get the hyper link for the column. I'm able to get the data but not the hyperlink.

This is the `HyperLinkTemplate` class which is implementing `ITemplate`.

```
public class HyperLinkTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private string m_ColumnName;
    public string ColumnName
    {
        get { return m_ColumnName; }
        set { m_ColumnName = value; }
    }

    public HyperLinkTemplate()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public HyperLinkTemplate(string ColumnName)
    {
        this.ColumnName = ColumnName;

    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control ThisColumn)
    {
        HyperLink HyperLinkItem = new HyperLink();
        HyperLinkItem.ID = "hl" + ColumnName;
        HyperLinkItem.DataBinding += HyperLinkItem_DataBinding;
        ThisColumn.Controls.Add(HyperLinkItem);

    }

    private void HyperLinkItem_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HyperLink HyperLinkItem = (HyperLink)sender;
        GridViewRow CurrentRow = (GridViewRow)HyperLinkItem.NamingContainer;
        object CurrentDataItem = DataBinder.Eval(CurrentRow.DataItem, ColumnName);
        HyperLinkItem.Text = CurrentDataItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't think that you should have to build your own template class for this.

You might mean something other than what I'm thinking by the term "dynamic gridview", but if you need to add a hyperlink to each row of a column in a GridView, and if you need to do this in the code-behind, then I would suggest handling the GridView's RowDataBound event and doing something like the following in the event handler:

```
    protected void grdData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
            link.Text = "This is a link!";
            link.NavigateUrl = "Navigate somewhere based on data: " + e.Row.DataItem;
            e.Row.Cells[ColumnIndex.Column1].Controls.Add(link);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great I was able to create the hyperlink as you said. But now I need to have a popup on clicking the hyperlink. One parameter needs to passed to the popup screen. Any idea ??

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  There are a couple of ways to do that. I'd say the easiest way would be to use javascript to create another window.  You could create a javascript function such as this, and pass in the url with your parameter in the query string:
function createWindow(url) {
 var newWindow = window.open(url, "newWindow", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=650,height=500");
}

Another option is to use Microsoft's Ajax Control Toolkit, which includes some nice popup functionality.  My experience suggests that it is not too hard to work with if you keep it simple.

Comment: i have .csv file to open on hyperlink click...can you please help me regarding to this? Thank you.

Comment: @shruti first decide how a client/browser will access your .csv file on the server (i.e. what URL the client will use to access the file). Is the .csv a static file?  If so, you could consider just putting the actual .csv file inside of your website and then just assign the appropriate URL pointing to it as the target URL of your hyperlink. Is the .csv file dynamically generated by the server? You could use a custom ASP.NET handler to write the .csv content directly to the response stream. Search the site for similar questions, but if none are helpful you could ask this as a new question.

Comment: Hello @Avi could someone please assist on the same issue? i have been following it up with fews days and still yet to get the correct answer.