# How to add header columns as Hyperlinks dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I'm adding columns dynamically to the gridview as:

```
    foreach (Countries country in CountryLst )
    {
        TemplateField templatefield = new TemplateField();
        tfield.HeaderText = "Header" + country;
        gridview1.Columns.Add(templatefield);
    }
```

Now I want make those column headers as `Hyperlink`, how can I achieve the same with `Hyperlink`

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288215/dynamically-add-hyperlink-in-gridview and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819381/how-to-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-dynamic-gridview-column  with small changes they will work for you

Comment: I have seen that, but they are not displays as `hyperlink` buttons

Comment: What do you mean not shown as hyperlink buttons ? If you want buttons then you should use the `LinkButton`, because `Hyperlink` will render as `<a />`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done in the past in a similar situation:

```
tfield.HeaderText = String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", "url.aspx", "text to display");
```